# Como mostra alert ao marcar checkbox em uma tabela?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela:

[image]

As informações mostradas são buscadas no banco, e do lado da coluna (neste exemplo) - Salary - terá uma coluna chamada **Bloquear / Desbloquear** - onde eu poderei bloquear aquela informação no banco (mudando o valor de 0 para 1) e assim antes do nome - exemplo **Ashton Cox** terá um ícone verde que significa desbloqueado e um vermelho se caso estiver bloqueado.

Ao marcar a *checkbox*, eu queria que aparecesse um alert *"Tem certeza de que quer bloquear?"* e a mesma coisa pra desbloquear *"Tem certeza de que quer desbloquear?"*

Como eu estou fazendo:

```
<tbody>
  <?php

      while($linhaAssociativa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
      { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Name"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Position"]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Office"]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Age"]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Start date"]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $linhaAssociativa["Salary"]?></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="muda" id="muda" /></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
      } ?>

</tbody>
```

Eu não estou conseguindo fazer o código javascript/jquery para que:
**ao marcar a checkbox de uma linha dessas da tabela mostre se não estiver bloqueado: "Tem certeza de quer quer bloquear?" ou mostre se estiver bloqueado: "Tem certeza de que quer desbloquear?" - num alert e mude o valor de 0 para 1 ou 1 para 0**

Comment: Criar um arquivo JS cara pra fazer isso, assim você vai consegui capturar a ação do click na checkbox e alterar de bloqueado pra desbloqueado e vice-versa .

Comment: Você já fez algum script ?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta e coloquei em negrito qual é a minha real dúvida.
@DotNet Não fiz nenhum script ainda. O que eu tenho medo que aconteça: como as checkbox estão sendo geradas dentro daquele while, elas não vão gerar com o mesmo id/name? Se sim, ao marcar pra bloquear, ela não iria bloquear todas as linhas?

Comment: Dentro de cada novo checkbox? E o script pra "bloquera/desbloquear" e mostrar um alert antes... Como ficaria? Ou melhor dizendo.. Como eu faria o script pra selecionar determinado checkbox?

Answer (score 6):

Faz algo assim:

No HTML:

```
<input name="muda" type="checkbox" onchange="mudar(this);">
```

No JavaScript:

```
function mudar(obj){
    var selecionado = obj.checked;
    if (selecionado) {
        alert('Tem certeza de quer quer bloquear?');
    } else {
        alert('Tem certeza de que quer desbloquear?');
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicionei, mas ao clicar na checkbox nada acontece...

Comment: @CesarA.Fonseca Algum erro no console do navegador?

Answer (score 2):

Segue o exemplo. Dessa forma, vai funcionar para todos os checkbox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
      alert('Tem certeza de que quer desbloquear?');
      return true;
    }
    alert('Tem certeza de quer quer bloquear?');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```